# Modify an .iso image

Tags: iso-image

I am curious whether it is possible to edit the .iso image of a live system, so that I could add/remove some custom packages in order to use them even after I shut down the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am curious whether it is possible to edit the .iso image

Remastering a livecd image is certainly possible, but the specific procedure depends on the livecd.  With sysresccd.org for example almost everything you want to change is within a compressed filesystem that is on the iso filesystem.  So you need to update/modify the compressed filesystem, and then use that to rebuild a new ISO image.

Many livecds implement things in different ways.

You need to either check the docs for your specific livecd, or spend time reverse engineering how exactly it works.

If you want to build a livecd of your own, there are many guides, and tools that will help you generate a CD that has exactly what you want.  I use the Debian [live tools](http://live.debian.net/) to build a CD that has a set of packages that are useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linux it would be possible to mount an ISO image as a file system and then edit its contents. To do this try the following (as root)

```
# mount -o loop disk.iso /mnt/pt
```

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-iso-image-under-linux.html)

Note: You will need to create the mount point location

Comment: this mounts my .iso file in read-only mode :/ .

Answer (score 0):

If you have GUI you can use PeaZip to edit the contents of an ISO image. You can find the project's page here http://peazip.sourceforge.net/ and you can download the .deb file for direct installation at Ubuntu or other related distributions from here http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-linux.html